# Keyboard Shortcut to toggle between Google search type tabs [Images, Maps, etc.] on SERP?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, google-search, search-engines

Is there a way to navigate or toggle between Google Search types via Keyboard Shortcut?

For example, on the Google Search Engine Results Page I'd like to press:

`i` to select the `Images` tab

`n` to select the `News` tab

`m` to select the `Maps` tab

`w` to select the `Web` tab

I find that I spend a lot of time mousing to click the `Images` tab, multiple times per day. It would be much nicer to have a keyboard shortcut that toggled to `Image` search.

[image: Select these tabs via keyboard shortcut]

Additionally, a couple years ago Google began **reordering** the list of search types based on the likelihood that you'll click that search product. [I'd like to find a way to stop the reordering, as well.](https://superuser.com/questions/1218989/how-to-maintain-order-of-the-google-search-type-links-images-maps-etc-rath)

[image: Images search link 4th in line.]

This forces me to *hunt down* the correct link to click. I can't always click the first link for `Images`, the second link for `Maps`, etc. A keyboard shortcut that always selects `Images` would save me from this cognitive searching cost.

Comment: I don't know of any native way to do this. I would imagine it can be done thru a custom [Chrome extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted) but I have never tried writing one, so I can't really advise you on that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the chrome extension [Vimium](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vimium/dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb?hl=en) to accomplish this. While the main purpose is to allow you to use vim shortcuts in chrome, its worth the installation solely for its link-clicking feature.

When vimium is enabled, you can press f on any page and each link will be highlighted with a character, which you can then type and the link will be automatically clicked. They also have capital F for open-in-new-tab.